# iOS Simple Predicate 'contains' Not Working

Tags: ios, core-data, predicate

I have a model:

place<--->>category

When performing the following query:

```
NSFetchRequest *req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Category"];
if(![searchText isEqualToString:@""] && searchText != nil){
    req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(places.placeTitle contains %@) OR (places.details contains %@) OR (name contains %@)", searchText, searchText, searchText];
    NSLog(@"ModelHelper.getResults: Search text given, creating predicate: %@", req.predicate);
}
req.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                                                             ascending:YES
                                                                              selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:req
                                                                            managedObjectContext:context
                                                                              sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                       cacheName:nil];
NSError *error = nil;
[controller performFetch:&error];
```

I receive matches that should not be there, for example:

```
searchText = "1234"
```

the first results are:

```
category[0].name = "Bars"
category[0].places[0].placeTitle = "Aaa"
category[0].places[0].details = "Aaa"
category[0].places[1].placeTitle = "123456"
category[0].places[1].details = "123456"
category[0].places[2].placeTitle = "test"
category[0].places[2].details = "test"
```

Is there something I am doing wrong with my predicate? Thanks.

Comment: req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(places.placeTitle CONTAINS %@) OR (places.details CONTAINS %@) OR (name CONTAINS %@)", searchText, searchText, searchText];

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> > Important: You must not modify fetchRequest after invoking this method. For example, you must not change its predicate or the sort orderings.

Move this segment:

```
if(![searchText isEqualToString:@""] && searchText != nil){
    req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(places.placeTitle contains[c] %@) OR (places.details contains[c] %@) OR (name contains[c] %@)", searchText, searchText, searchText];
    NSLog(@"ModelHelper.getResults: Search text given, creating predicate: %@", req.predicate);
}
```

Before you initialize the FRC

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing as you suggested (as shown in the updated code above) but I am still getting the exact same behavior.

Comment: But your results match the predicate: places[2].placeTitle = "1234..."

Comment: Yes, the the results contain items that do not match. places[1] does not have a title, or details that match "1234".

Comment: But you requested results entity to be `Category` and the result category answers the predicate

Comment: So, does that mean that it will return all of places that exist in a category, if one of the places in the category matches? how would i create a query that will only return the results as an array of categories that only contain places where the placeTitle or details match? is that possible with a single query? thanks.

Comment: CoreDat is issuing a fetch per entity, it is not possible to filter the relationships of the returned results (this is an object graph) in the query itself, the relationship is faulted as it is accessed.